# Using functions to rename a character variable

Tags: r, function, paste

I have a data frame where the first column is a character variable standing for the districts in a country, and other columns contain some numerical data. I want to add a suffix to the names in the first column so as to indicate the region the districts belong to. Let's say "NR" to the first two, "BB" from the third to the fifth (and the rows could continue with other districts)

```
D=data.frame("Col1" = c("Levice", "Nitra", "Brezno", "Detva", "Zvolen"),
                     "Col2" = 1:5, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I figured that I could do this with the code:

```
D$Col1[1:2]=paste(D$Col1[1:2],"NR", sep=".")
D$Col1[3:5]=paste(D$Col1[3:5],"BB", sep=".")
```

So I get this:

```
Col1        Col2
Levice.NR   1
Nitra.NR    2
Brezno.BB   3
Detva.BB    4
Zvolen.BB   5
```

However, if I try to put the code into a function, the result is not stored in my data frame:

```
Suffix=function(X1){
D1=(X1=D$Col1[1:2])
paste(D$Col1[1:2],"NR", sep=".")
}
Suffix(D)
"Levice.NR" "Nitra.NR"
```

or if I modify it, does not work:

```
Suffix=function(X1){
D1=(X1=D$Col1[1:2])
D$Col1[1:2]=paste(D$Col1[1:2],"NR", sep=".")
}
Suffix(D)
#just nothing happens to the data frame
```

Can you please help what's wrong with the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions in R should not modify values outside of themselves. The fact that functions should not have "side-effects" is a core principle of function programming (and R is a functional programming language). When you attempt to modify a variable from outside the function scope, the function makes changes to a copy only accessible inside the function.

The right thing to do is to return a modified object and do the re-assignment outside the function

```
Suffix <- function(X) {
    X$Col1[1:2] <- paste(X$Col1[1:2],"NR", sep=".")
    return(X)
}
D <- Suffix(D)
```

Comment: I see, but the suggested code doesn't work for some reason. It gives the following error: "Error in X$Col1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Comment: Are you passing in the original data frame to the function?

Comment: Oops, sorry, it works -- thank you! Can I ask you what does "return" do in your function, and how come you replaced D$Col1 in the second line for X$Col1? Should not the argument (X1) and object (D1) be too separate items?

Comment: `return()` returns the updated vale from the function. I'm not sure what `X1` and `D1` are supposed to be. I take the object passed in as a parameter, transform it, then return the transformed version. It's easiest to understand when functions don't reference variables outside their scope.

Comment: I just used X1 because I read in an Intro to R book (Zuur et al 2009, p.110) that it was safer to use names that didn't exist outside the function. I'm not sure about the use of D1 either. I used this code as my model: 

`NAPerVariable <- function(X1) {
D1 <- is.na(X1)
colSums(D1)
}`

and I understand that X (or X1) is the main object here, but need to spend some time to digest how the one you suggested is different from this one.  Thank you for your feedback, I really appreciate it.